# How to get gradients to work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, gradient

I am making a naviagtion bar with a gradient as follows:

```
/* Gradient backgrounds for the buttons. Generated using http://gradients.glrzad.com/ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #b49931), color-stop(0.5, #5E5E5E), color-stop(0.51, #707070), color-stop(1, #838383));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #787878 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%);
background-color:#5f5f5f; /* Fallback */
```

it works great in safari but does not work firefox. I know making an image would be better but is there any easy way that it will work in firefox aswell as safari?

Comment: Is there something that you cannot find the answer for in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BVbfQ/
You can use Safari to make a screenshot of the result and crop it to make a repeatable image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool. Works in all browsers

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Works in all browsers? Uh, you might want to check IE. In IE 7-9, you have to use extensions such as [pie css](http://css3pie.com/) in order to get gradients to work. If you even try to load the page you linked to in IE, it tells you that it does not fully support it.

Comment: i said all browsers, not all versions of all browsers.